# multiple mysql JOINs with Aggregate functions

Tags: sql

im trying to join 3 tables

Article, Stock and Sold tables
[image]

i want to select for each article the sum of its QteEntree from the table Stock and the sum of
Qte from the table Sold
here s my code

```
Select  Article.IdArt,
        Sum(sold.Qte),
        Sum(Stock.QteEntree)
from (((Article) 
        Left Join Sold on Sold.IdArt = Article.IdArt)
        Left Join Stock on Stock.IdArt = Article.IdArt)
Group by Article.IdArt
```

but i always get (for a example) for the IdArt multiplied result by 2 for the QteEntree
and multiplied result by 3 for the Qte
i guess because i have 2 records in the Sold table and 3 record in the Stock table

how can i fix this?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a shot using sub-queries:

```
select a.IdArt,
       (select sum(Qte) from Sold where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as QteSum,
       (select sum(QteEntree) from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as QteEntreeSum
from Article a
```

Comment: Is this query efficient for large datasets?