# IIF Statement in Ms-Access

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I have these 3 tables: 
[image]

and I'm using this code to join them together (I'm using Delphi):

```
ADOQ.SQL.Text := 'select a.IdArt as [Code d''Article], '+
                   'a.Nom,'+
                   'Str(a.Prix)+" TND" as Prix, '+
                   '(select Str(sum(QteEntree))+" "+a.unit from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as [Quantite Entree],' +
                   '(select Str(sum(Qte))+" "+a.unit from Sold where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as [Quantite Vendu],'+
                   'Str((select sum(QteEntree) from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) -' +
                   '(select sum(Qte) from Sold where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt))+" "+a.unit as [Quantite Existe]'+

                   'from Article a ';
```

[image]

As you can see, when there is a missing record from one table, it returns Null to the DbGrid, 
so I want to replace that missing record with "0". 
I tried this code:

```
ADOQ.SQL.Text := 'select a.IdArt as [Code d''Article], '+
                   'a.Nom,'+
                   'Str(a.Prix)+" TND" as Prix, '+
                   '(select Str(sum(QteEntree))+" "+a.unit from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as [Quantite Entree],' +
                   '(select IIF( IsNull(sum(Qte)), "111" , Format( sum(Qte),"00.00") ) from Sold where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) as [Quantite Vendu],'+
                   'Str((select sum(QteEntree) from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) -' +
                   '(select sum(Qte) from Sold where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt))+" "+a.unit as [Quantite Existe]'+

                   'from Article a ';
```

but nothing changed, although this code works perfectly :

```
ADOQ.SQL.Text := 'Select a.IdArt,IIF(( IsNull( s.qte) ), "00,00" , Format( (s.qte),"00.00") ) from Article a left join sold s on s.IdArt = a.IdArt';
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of data, there are of very little use compared to even the most unformatted sample of data. A sample can be used to reproduce the problem, but no one is going to type the data from a picture to test it.

Comment: Have you tested the above query inside Ms-Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the solution :

```
iif( isnull((select sum(QteEntree) from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt)) ,0, (select sum(QteEntree) from Stock where IdArt = a.IdArt group by IdArt) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the " group by IdArt" parts - they seem unnecessary since you're already excluding all others in the WHERE clause.

Otherwise, something like this might be an improvement in how you're writing your query:

```
select 
    a.IdArt as [Code d''Article], 
    a.Nom,
    Str(a.Prix)+" TND" as Prix, 
    Str(sum(stock.QteEntree))+" "+a.unit as [Quantite Entree],
    IIF( IsNull(sum(sold.Qte)), "111" , Format( sum(sold.Qte),"00.00") ) as [Quantite Vendu],
    Str(sum(stock.QteEntree) - sum(sold.Qte))+" "+a.unit as [Quantite Existe]

from Article a 
left join stock on a.IdArt = stock.IdArt
left join sold on a.IdArt = sold.IdArt
group by a.IdArt, a.Nom, a.Prix, a.unit
```

*You might need to tweak that though*

Actually, I'd prefer to write this statement from above:

```
IIF( IsNull(sum(sold.Qte)), "111" , Format( sum(sold.Qte),"00.00") ) as [Quantite Vendu],
```

Like this instead:

```
Format( sum( IIF( IsNull( sold.Qte ) , 0, sold.Qte ) ), "00.00" ) as [Quantite Vendu],
```

*Againt, I'm not 100% sure that would work, I'm just looking at the order & logic of your functions*

Comment: the formatting thing works but it leads to my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337355/multiple-mysql-joins-with-aggregate-functions    wrong results...